# get span jsname = 'value' , selenium, python

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am truly sorry for terrible question formulation, and incredibly thankful for the answers

QUESTION - How do I get span jsname = 'bN97Pc' in my example case. Python and selenium:
screenshot[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get  `jsname = 'bN97Pc'` using `jsname` attribute name, you could use `.get_attribute()`

using below xpath

```
//img[contains(@src, 'https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a-/')]/../following-sibling::div/div[@jscontroller]/span
```

something like this :

```
ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@src, 'https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a-/')]/../following-sibling::div/div[@jscontroller]/span")))
print(ele.get_attribute('jsname'))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: since I am a newbie I got scared of the lengthy solution and applied @Rohit solution which was so short. but THANK YOU for the answer

Comment: His solution won't work if the value of janame changes, mine will be more stable, give it a try don't be afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below xpath

```
//span[@jsname = 'bN97Pc']
```

Comment: WORKED! Thank you so very much. I would extract the actual text by looping during the scraping        and getting  driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@jsname= "bN97Pc"]')[0].text       works. Do you know a better method?